# How to display knowledge Articles for community users using lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, knowledge

I am trying to display knowledge articles on lightning component. When I use same query in developer console its working fine. I have given Knowledge Article object permission to community users, but still the list is returning null.

**Component:**

```
    <aura:component controller="articlecontroller" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:attribute type="String" name="set" default=""/>        
<aura:attribute name="articles" type="Knowledge_Article__kav" />
        <aura:handler event="c:getEvent" action="{!c.onChange}"/>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.articles))}">
             <aura:iteration items="{!v.articles}" var="art">
                <tr>
                    <td>{!art.Id}</td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </aura:if>

    </aura:component>
```

**Controller.js:**

```
onChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.set",event.getParam("set"));
        helper.getArts(component, event, helper);

    }
```

**Helper:**

```
({
    getArts : function(component, event, helper)
    {

        var action = component.get('c.getArticles');
        action.setParams({  
           set :component.get("v.set")
        });

        action.setCallback(this,function(response){

            var sets = response.getSet();
            //checkCard = true;
            if (sets === "SUCCESS") {

                console.log("--articles**",response.getReturnValue());
                component.set('v.articles', "");
                component.set('v.articles', response.getReturnValue());

            }else if(state === "ERROR"){
               // do something
                }else {
                    throw new Error("Unknown Error");
                }
            }

        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    },

})
```

Apex Controller:

```
@AuraEnabled

    public static List<Knowledge_Article__kav> getArticles(String set) {

                List<Knowledge_Article__kav> articles_List = new  List<Knowledge_Article__kav>();
        articles_List = [select  Id,Title,KnowledgeArticleId from Knowledge_Article__kav WHERE Language =:'en_US' AND PublishStatus =:'Online']
         return articles_List;
        }
```

Comment: So, you are trying to assign a list of knowledge articles to a  sobject type or string? You probably want to reevalute the attribute type to which you are assigning the response to, and clarify where exactly you are getting a null value

Comment: @glls I am adding to Sobject. String is to pass parameter to apex controller to query which contains that set value.